# providing a c# dataset to a SOAP server from PHP SOAP Client

Tags: c#, php, soap, dataset

I am trying to utilize a third party SOAP api. The api was evidently created with c#, and it uses a dataset - i.e. complex data.

My soap client is in PHP.

I expected to be able to do something like this:

```
class Person {
        function Person ($email) {
                $this->FieldName = SOME_CONSTANT;
                $this->FieldValue = $email;
                }
        }

$signOn = array("UserName" => "myUserName", "PassWord" => "myPassWord");

$sp = new SoapClient("https://lab6.xxxxxxxxxhost.com/xxxxxxxxx/gwwebgst.asmx?WSDL", $signOn);
$person = new Person ("joe@joeDomain.com");
$params = array("parintStart" => 0,
                "parintEnd" => 1000,
                "parstrSortBy" => 0,
                "parblnSortAsc" => true,
                "parOUTintCount" => 0,
                "pardstGST" => $person);

$ret = $sp->__soapCall("ReadGuestListSearch", array($params));
```

But that gives me a response of something like this:
SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in GW01.php:27

I have tried the following:

1) $person as an array('FieldName' =>... 'FieldValue' => ...); same result.

2) creating $person as a string of XML based on the 3rd party's specs. same result.

3) searching for a way to build the dataset as straight binary data - i did not find the specs but still think that might work.

Question:
a) Does anyone have a way of communicating from PHP to SOAP via a fabricated dataset?

b) Does anyone know if that is necessary? Is there an easier way for me to be doing this? (The ultimate goal is to pass the 3rd party 2 pieces of information and get appropriate data back.)

I would so much appreciate any guidance or help!

Thanks in advance.